# How do I solve $0 = x\times114 - x\times\log_3(x) - 20.28\times y$ in matlab for different values of $y$?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions, matlab, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have $y = 10^3, 10^6, 10^9, 10^{12}, 10^{15}, ...$ and above mentioned equation. 
How do I solve (i.e. getting values of x for different y) and plot this equation in MATLAB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For finding zeros you can use fzero, you just have to use a starting value $x_0$.

x0  = 10;

y=10^3;

f = @(x) 114*x-log(abs(x))/log(3) .* x - 20.28*y;

fzero(f,x0);

You then have to check whether the solution is greater than $0$ because we used $log(|x|)$.

For implicit plots (as you seemed to ask first) you can use following functions:
You can use the [contour](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) function for implicit plots: Just provide a nullvector as levels. Other functions for implicit plots are [implot](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/300-implot-m), [implot2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23548-implot2-m), and [ezplot](http://www.mathworks.ch/help/matlab/ref/ezplot.html).

Comment: Thanks for reply but I am dumb to math and MATLAB can you suggest code for the same ? Please. I am not sure if these functions can give me values of X for any particular Y.

Comment: I see you have updated your question, I will update my answer.